# How do I reach the compartment before it closes in Chapter 3?

Tags: agent-a-a-puzzle-in-disguise

In chapter 3, there is a button on the ground to the right of a platform in the center of the room. Clicking the button opened a compartment on the left side of the platform. The compartment keeps closing before I can reach it.

How do I reach the compartment before it closes?

[image: compartment closing before I can reach it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to weigh the switch down with something heavy to keep it open.

While the object you need is hidden in plain sight, you can't actually get to it until you progress the room a bit.

Specifically:

> You need to find the chisel and use it to get the brick from the left wall

So where is that item?

> First you need to solve the puzzle to get the first power cell, then find the 3 clues for the blue grid and solve that.  This will unlock the pull switch that converts the room to its second form.

> Once the room is transformed, use the pencil to open the grate on the left side and grab the Chisel.  You can then pull the switch to transform the room back and chisel the brick out of the wall.